# Transforms a null field with awk

Tags: awk

I have a string like:

```
Topic: test1    TopicId: IMjrpzIARVyMPVgxRC1dsA PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: message.format.version=2.8-IV1,message.timestamp.type=CreateTime,min.insync.replicas=1
Topic: test2    TopicId: KFkR8ukRQXif1nvjQAcwZA PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact
Topic: d9nvrvth TopicId: 5Ec71za3TV-KznAnG8nV0Q PartitionCount: 6   ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: message.format.version=2.3-IV1,cleanup.policy=delete,max.message.bytes=2097164,min.compaction.lag.ms=0,message.timestamp.type=CreateTime,min.insync.replicas=2,segment.bytes=104857600,segment.ms=604800000,retention.ms=604800000,message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807,delete.retention.ms=86400000,retention.bytes=-1
```

And I want to select just 2 fields(cleanup.policy and retention.ms), but sometime this fields are not present on the string.
When those fields are not present i want to put a default value.

I use this awk sentence

```
awk '
            match($0,/Topic:[^\t]*/){
            topic=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
            match($0,/retention\.ms[^,]*/)
            retention=substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)
            if ( length(retention == 0) retention = "1 week"
            match($0,/cleanup\.policy[^,]*/)
            clean=substr($0,RSTART+15,RLENGTH-15)
            if ( length(clean == 0) clean = "delete"
            print topic","retention,","clean }'
```

But the problems is that always give me the same value

Comment: `if ( length(retention == 0)` should be just `if (retention == "")`

Comment: [edit] your question to add the expected output. And please fix the syntax errors in your code and add some line breaks, indents, and other common formatting constructs that make code legible to your code.

Comment: just to confirm ... your ***string*** consists of 3 lines of text? or is that 3 separate examples of strings you're dealing with? or is that 3 lines from a file that you need to parse? (trying to understand if the input is coming from a multi-line variable, a file, or something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues with OP's current `awk` code:

- no attempt is made to capture the values for the `retention.ms` and `cleanup.policy` attributes
- `/retention\.ms/` matches both `retention.ms` and `delete.retention.ms` so the `match()` will find whichever one comes first in `Configs:` section
- the `print` is printing the literal strings `"retention"` and `"clean"` instead of the contents of the variables `retention` and `clean`

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
$1 == "Topic:" { topic=$2
                 retention="1 week"                    # set default value
                 clean="delete"                        # set default value

                 n=split($NF,a,/[,=]/)                 # split last field on dual delimiters "," and "=";
                                                       # odd indexed entries are attributes, even indexed entries are values

                 for (i=1;i<=n;i+=2) {                 # loop through list of attributes
                     if (a[i]=="retention.ms")         # if we have an attribute match then ...
                        retention=a[i+1]               # save value
                     if (a[1]=="cleanup.policy")       # if we have an attribute match then ...
                        clean=a[i+1]                   # save value
                 }

                 print topic, retention, clean
               }
' topic.dat
```

This generates:

```
test1 1 week delete
test2 1 week compact
d9nvrvth 604800000 delete
```